# Set a FrameLayout as the background of an xml layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this is probably simple but I have an xml file in android that contains a number of buttons along with a FrameLayout that displays the preview from the camera on the phone. I want this FrameLayout to be in the background of the screen and all the other buttons and such to appear on top/above of it. Ive tried using the "gravity" and setting the FrameLayout as the background of the linearLayout its all built in but nothing works. Any idea how i would be able to do this.

EDIT:
Here is my code. I tried putting the Framelayout with the preview on the top and buttons on the buttom but when testing it doesnt work well so now i want to place the framelayout in the background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
  <!-- <1> -->
    <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/buttonClick" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Click" android:layout_x="104dip" android:layout_y="161dip" android:gravity="top"></Button>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Hat" android:layout_x="-4dip" android:layout_y="258dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/hatbox" android:layout_x="-10dip" android:layout_y="202dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/shirtbox" android:layout_x="28dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/beltbox" android:layout_x="64dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pantbox" android:layout_x="100dip" android:layout_y="202dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/shoebox" android:layout_x="140dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/accbox" android:layout_x="181dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/jacketbox" android:layout_x="220dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dressbox" android:layout_x="257dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shirt" android:layout_x="33dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Belt" android:layout_x="72dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Pants" android:layout_x="101dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shoes" android:layout_x="140dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Acc" android:layout_x="189dip" android:layout_y="258dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Dress" android:layout_x="261dip" android:layout_y="261dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView07" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Jacket" android:layout_x="220dip" android:layout_y="258dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_height="200dip" android:visibility="invisible" android:id="@+id/preview" android:layout_width="300dip" android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="2dip"></FrameLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
  <!-- <2> -->
  <!-- <3> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT2:
So it was working great and i was just about to tell you but sudenly i broke it.... I was adjusting where the buttons are on the screen and now the buttons are no longer visible. Heres my code... any idea?

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
  <!-- <1> -->
    <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout2" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:visibility="visible" android:id="@+id/preview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_x="0dip" android:layout_y="0dip">
            <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/buttonClick" android:layout_y="161dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Click" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="130dip"></Button>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="258dip" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Hat" android:layout_x="15dip"></TextView>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/hatbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="10dip" android:layout_y="200dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="201dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/shirtbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="50dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="201dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/beltbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="90dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="202dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/pantbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="130dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="201dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/shoebox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="170dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="201dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/accbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="210dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="201dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/jacketbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="247dip"></CheckBox>
                <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="201dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:id="@+id/dressbox" android:gravity="top" android:layout_x="285dip"></CheckBox>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="257dip" android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Shirt" android:layout_x="55dip"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="257dip" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Belt" android:layout_x="95dip"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="257dip" android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Pants" android:layout_x="130dip"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="257dip" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Shoes" android:layout_x="170dip"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="258dip" android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Acc" android:layout_x="220dip"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="261dip" android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Dress" android:layout_x="285dip"></TextView>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_y="258dip" android:id="@+id/TextView07" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:gravity="top" android:text="Jacket" android:layout_x="247dip"></TextView>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
  <!-- <2> -->
  <!-- <3> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: IS this an AR app? Why not draw your camera and then place a transparent framelayout over it to insert your items?

Comment: Oh no im sorry. Its just a few buttons to choose what type of picture is being taken so that it can be placed in the correct folder. For example if its a picture of a shirt the user selects the shirt check box and it gets put into the shirt images folder

Comment: Oh, well. Check my answer. It should create the effect you're looking for. If not comment and I'll try to help more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you want to do is have the camera preview in the background and a layout on top with all your buttons etc. I'm assuming this is some sort of AR app.

To achieve this, make your preview and put it in as the background as you have done, now just make another layout to sit on top of this layout. Make it's background transparent and put all your items on that.

Since you say you have the Camera done fine, I'll describe the second layout.

Set background of this view to be  transparent using

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

So, now you can see the camera. great! Simply add your buttons etc. as normal onto this view and you will create the effect you're looking for.

**EDIT** Just to clarify, the second layout (the one with the buttons) would be a child of the camera preview.

**EDIT:2** Haven't got the Android SDK with me right now, but I'll take a stab at this anyways...

All I did was make the Absolute inside your Camera preview layout transparent. Try that code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
<!-- <1> -->
<AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/buttonClick" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Click" android:layout_x="104dip" android:layout_y="161dip" android:gravity="top"></Button>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Hat" android:layout_x="-4dip" android:layout_y="258dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/hatbox" android:layout_x="-10dip" android:layout_y="202dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/shirtbox" android:layout_x="28dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/beltbox" android:layout_x="64dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/pantbox" android:layout_x="100dip" android:layout_y="202dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/shoebox" android:layout_x="140dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/accbox" android:layout_x="181dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/jacketbox" android:layout_x="220dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/dressbox" android:layout_x="257dip" android:layout_y="201dip" android:gravity="top"></CheckBox>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shirt" android:layout_x="33dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Belt" android:layout_x="72dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Pants" android:layout_x="101dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Shoes" android:layout_x="140dip" android:layout_y="257dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Acc" android:layout_x="189dip" android:layout_y="258dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Dress" android:layout_x="261dip" android:layout_y="261dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView07" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Jacket" android:layout_x="220dip" android:layout_y="258dip" android:gravity="top"></TextView>
    <FrameLayout android:layout_height="200dip" android:visibility="invisible" android:id="@+id/preview" android:layout_width="300dip" android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="2dip"></FrameLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
<!-- <2> -->
<!-- <3> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT3**

Just some further clarification. The app I'm describing has the Camera preview in the linear layout. you put the absolute inside it as it's child. Set it's background to transparent so it's background is now the camera preview. After doing all of this you append your buttons etc. to the absolute layout creating the effect I've linked in the comments below.

Comment: But why was this line transparent? Doesnt it have the preview under it. I thought the preview was going to parent and the buttons the children. This seems to be the opposite? no? <AbsoluteLayout android:id="@+id/absoluteLayout1" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

Comment: You want to create some sort of effect like this: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Wikitude.jpg no? Where you have the Camera under and you can draw your elements over it. By doing this you have the Camera preview in the LinearLayout and when you set the absolute to being transparent the "background" becomes the camera preview and your button's and rendered on top of the camera.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I'm looking to do. I'm going to try to make it work now and get back to you, thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problem, I'll be around for the next while. If you have any further difficulties let me know! It'd be nice to know you got it sorted in the end too! :)